# NestedScrollView not scrolling issue with Fragment of FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nestedscrollview, android-framelayout

I have used `FrameLayout` as a `Fragment` container inside `NestedScrollView`. It works fine when loading first `Fragment` in `FrameLayout` (Scrolling) but when i replace another `Fragment` in `FrameLayout` then it stopped showing content and scrolling as well

I tried set property `android:fillViewport="true"` in `NestedScrollview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtName"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_add_round"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgProfile"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgProfile" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/text_dark"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgProfile"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgProfile"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgProfile" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/app_yellow" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to scroll as `Fragment` Content but it works only first time

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?